# Try Catch inside Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

What's the best way to write the following code:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    try
    {
        SendEmail(emailadress); //method that will send emails
        MessageSent(true);
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageSent(false);
        break;
    }
}

void MessageSent(Boolean IsSuccesful)
{
    if (IsSuccesful)
    {
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.Redirect("~/Page.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        lblSent.Text = "Email has failed.";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to iterate through a datatable and send an email to the different emails listed in the datatable and then redirect to Page.aspx on success after all of the emails in the datatable have been sent.  However, if the emails fail, I would like to show the label lblSent.  I just don't know if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried something? What happened?

Comment: It works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to write this.  I'm still new to .net

Comment: Why don't you queue up the target emails, then send it once? I feel like that's much more efficient than sending the email to each individual address.

Comment: That code looks fine to me. You might want to call MessageSent *outside* of the try/catch, so you don't get confused if it throws an exception. You could use a boolean variable to track whether the sending was a success or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among other things, you shouldn't be catching the `Exception` type. Only catch exceptions that you know how to handle. You cannot handle `NullReferenceException` or `ArgumentNullException`, so don't try. Catch only those exceptions which are likely to be thrown while sending an email. Things like `SmtpException` or `FormatException` (for email address format errors).